Starting an ElectronJS project but encountering this when running npm start: The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly
I am trying out ElectronJS for the first time as it seems like a pretty neat framework. I am working off of a Windows Subsystem for Linux. I managed to create my app using the following line
npx create-electron-app my-app

and I made sure to enter the directory that it created.
After doing so, I tried running
npm start

but I got a few errors that appeared to be just missing packages, I installed all those packages but now I met with this error.
[1513:1006/130848.123438:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(163)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /mnt/c/Users/A3_Digital/Desktop/CSV Generator/csv-generator/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.

Looking online, I found three supposed solutions that haven't worked for me.

Using change ownership and change mode commands

sudo chown root chrome-sandbox
sudo chmod 4755 chrome-sandbox

This results in
chown :cannot access 'chrome-sandbox': No such file or directory
chmod :cannot access 'chrome-sandbox': No such file or directory


Enabling unprivileged access

sudo sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1

This results in
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone: No such file or directory


Running with the launch argument --no-sandbox

npm start --no-sandbox

This results in the exact same error as the one without the launch argument.
I'm still learning a bit on the WSL side of things, so any help or suggestions is appreciated.

No such file or directory suggests that you need to change your current directory. What is the output of running pwd?

@nyarthan /mnt/c/Users/%MyUserName%/Desktop/%AppName%/%app-name%
Also, I have since found another Stackoverflow page that said chown and chmod only work on Native Linux partitions, which may have been where your question was going. However, I tried the same process from above while in the /home/ directory and got the same errors as before. Should I try another Linux partition?

I don't know enough about WSL to give you an answer to that. But I did notice that your current working directory (output of pwd) is still not correct. You need to change it to the directory that contains the files you want to execute commands on (/mnt/c/Users/A3_Digital/Desktop/CSV Generator/csv-generator/node_modules/electron/dist/). After that running a command that includes a relative path - in your case chrome-sandbox, it will resolve to file relative to your cwd.

Another solution is to directly use the full, absolute path to the file, so your command would be sudo chown root /mnt/c/Users/A3_Digital/Desktop/CSV Generator/csv-generator/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox (and other commands following similar structure). I would recommend reading this article to learn more about the linux file-system and paths.
